# Kubuntu 20.10 very high boot time

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, operating-system

Facing very high time  for Kubuntu 20.10.
Guide me with its optimization. Already tried online articles n few suggestion from this site without any success

Few details of system :

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.10

KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0

Qt Version: 5.14.2

Kernel Version: 5.8.0-55-generic

OS Type: 64-bit

Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz

Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM

Graphics Processor: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 3000

Storage : 1 TB (HDD) (sda) - in 2 partition (one for os (sda1) ,other for safe storage (sda2 ,sda5))

Output of systemd-analyze & systemd-analyze blame

[image]

Output of systemd-analyze critical-chain

[image]

Output of cat /etc/fstab

[image]

Comment: SO is for programming questions.  You should post that question on linux stack sites (ex. Ask Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for it, I'd like you to do an experiment. Open your fstab file as administrator and comment out the line for your swap by placing a # ahead of it and add the following line

```
/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

(afterwards just uncomment the line again)

Comment: Hi , 
I tried this but had no change in boot time.